# Change Origin of Shapes in Graph

Tags: graphing-functions

This might seem pretty simple, but keep in mind I'm in middle school.

I graphed a spiral using $r = \theta$. The problem is, the origin is at $(0, 0)$. How can I change the origin to something like $(0, 5)$?

I have the same problem with a semicircle. I have a semicircle graphed with $p=-\sqrt{4-y^2}$. I can change the $X$ axis by adding a $+$ sign after the square root, but I also want to change the $Y$ axis.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first question is hard.  There is no simple way to transform the simple polar coordinate ($r,\theta$) equation for a spiral originating at the origin, to a spiral originating elsewhere.  It can be done but not with things you know about in middle school.

The second question is easier.  Try something like

$$p = -\sqrt{4-(y-1)^2}$$
which forces $y$ to behave like $y+1$ used to behave.  Fool around with different valuews instead of that $-1$ to see what it does.

---

The ugly answer to the second question, if you insist on expressing the shifted spiral in polar coordinates is to temporarily work in $(x,y)$ coordinates, where the shifted spiral will be

$$\sqrt{x^2+(y-5)^2} = \tan^{-1}\frac{ y-5}{x}
$$
If you then take $$r = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$ and
$$\theta = \tan^{-1}\frac{y}{x}$$

you would have your curve.

Told you you didn't want to do that...

Comment: Can you still show me the answer for the first question?